# Views and casting to text

Tags: sql, postgresql, view

I have created a view which has 4 columns. It looks something like this

```
status         |     name        |       faculty     |    starting
Garbage value  |  James Donald   |   XYZ             |    2001-01-01  
"                 Ross Harley        ABC                  2013-04-04
```

It has more values but that's not of any concern. 
I need to replace the garbage value in status with text "Longest serving" or "Shortest serving"but cant seem to do that.

The answer should look something like

`status          |     name        |       faculty     |    starting                               Longest Serving  |  James Donald   |   XYZ             |    2001-01-01                Shortest Serving |  Ross Harley    |   ABC             |    2013-04-04`

My initial query to create the view q3 is:

```
create or replace view q3 (status, name, faculty, starting) as
select max(q.starting) as status, q.name, q.faculty, q.starting
from q2 q
where (starting in (select min(starting) from q2))
   or (starting in (select Max(starting) from q2))
group by q.name, q.faculty, q.starting;
```

max(q.starting) as stats is the garbage.

[The 2 views involved](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X7YoT.png)
What it's doing is essentially finding out who served the longest and shortest based on starting column. (data in view q2) and replace the status as either longest serving or shortest serving .

If you could understand the problem and know the solution, It would help me a great deal. Thanks.

Comment: Which dbms are you using?

Comment: psql in PostgreSql

Comment: Can you add some more sample data and also the expected result?

Comment: I am new here and don't know much about formatting it properly. Hope you understand what I'm trying to say. 
Thanks

Comment: You're doing fine. Add one or more two rows of sample data, to make things even clearer. What's the expected result if two different persons have the same first (or last) starting date? Do you want both to show up in the result?

Comment: If there are multiple values having same dates, they all should show up.

Comment: I've attached a photo if that helps

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following adaption to your query should work:

```
create or replace view q3 (status, name, faculty, starting) as
select 
  CASE
    WHEN starting in (select min(starting) from q2 THEN 'longest serving'
    ELSE 'shortest serving'
  END 
  AS status,
  q.name, q.faculty, q.starting
from q2 q
where (starting in (select min(starting) from q2))
   or (starting in (select Max(starting) from q2))
group by q.name, q.faculty, q.starting;
```